# Login as user hdfs failed:su: Authentication failure

Tags: 18.04, permissions, login, sudo

I ran this script to create users and groups

```
  groupadd hadoop
  useradd -g hadoop yarn
  useradd -g hadoop hdfs
  useradd -g hadoop mapred
```

But if I try to login

```
miki@miki:~$ su - hdfs
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

I have not submitted any password for my hdfs user.

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd output
yarn
hdfs
mapred
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I unterstand correct:

You created users wihtout password.

You need to create or mod the user with the `-p` flag:

`useradd -g hadoop hdfs -p encyptedpasswordbyopenssl`

The password needs to be in an encrypted format. Create it with `openssl passwd mypassword`